# How to replace a column value which is missing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset whose first two values of a column are, apparently missing, and I cannot change it!
Here is the dataset print:

```
                 data/hora  HumExamRoom                      HumTechRoom Machine  TempExamRoom TempTechRoom
0                                NaN  2017-08-18\t09:22:33\t65.9   74034           NaN          NaN
1                                NaN  2017-10-03\t11:08:26\t60.5   74034           NaN          NaN
2  2018-02-17\t01:45:24          NaN                             69.7   74034           NaN          NaN
3  2018-02-17\t01:45:55          NaN                             67.5   74034           NaN          NaN
4  2018-02-17\t01:46:29          NaN                             65.4   74034           NaN          NaN
5  2018-02-17\t01:47:20          NaN                             63.3   74034           NaN          NaN
6  2018-02-17\t01:48:35          NaN                             61.3   74034           NaN          NaN
7  2018-02-17\t01:49:08          NaN                             63.4   74034           NaN          NaN
8  2018-02-17\t01:49:31          NaN                             65.5   74034           NaN          NaN
9  2018-02-17\t01:49:55          NaN                             67.6   74034           NaN          NaN
```

AS you can see, for the rows 0 and 1 in the column 'data/hora' there are no values. I want to replace them with information in the column 3. I have tried many things, all of them had failed.

Such as:

```
df_74034.replace({df_74034.iloc[0,0] : '2017-08-18\t09:22:33'}, inplace=True)
```

Then I tried:

```
df_74034.at[0, 'data/hora'] = 0
```

And I got:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  return super(DataFrame, self).rename(**kwargs)
/home/marlon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:2584: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.loc[index, col] = value
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own problem. Here it goes:

We cannot change the data frame because it is, in fact, a copy of a data frame. Therefore, the methods we were imploying didn't work - to understand why to check http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html.

Hence, I had to change directly the data frame `df` from which `df_74034` came from. There I've just applied:

```
    df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True) 
df_74034.rename(index=str, columns={"index": "data/hora"}, inplace=True)
```

Then I printed `df_74034` and got their index, an so:

```
df.loc[69333, 'index'] = '2017-08-18\t09:22:33'
df.loc[69334, 'index'] = '2017-10-03\t11:08:26' 
df.loc[69333, 'HumTechRoom'] = '65.9' 
df.loc[69334, 'HumTechRoom'] = '60.5'
```

which gave me:

```
 data/hora  HumExamRoom HumTechRoom Machine  TempExamRoom TempTechRoom
69333  2017-08-18\t09:22:33          NaN        65.9   74034           NaN          NaN
69334  2017-10-03\t11:08:26          NaN        60.5   74034           NaN          NaN
69335  2018-02-17\t01:45:24          NaN        69.7   74034           NaN          NaN
69336  2018-02-17\t01:45:55          NaN        67.5   74034           NaN          NaN
69337  2018-02-17\t01:46:29          NaN        65.4   74034           NaN          NaN
69338  2018-02-17\t01:47:20          NaN        63.3   74034           NaN          NaN
69339  2018-02-17\t01:48:35          NaN        61.3   74034           NaN          NaN
69340  2018-02-17\t01:49:08          NaN        63.4   74034           NaN          NaN
69341  2018-02-17\t01:49:31          NaN        65.5   74034           NaN          NaN
69342  2018-02-17\t01:49:55          NaN        67.6   74034           NaN          NaN
```

I know there should be a more elegant and smart way to do what I've done. But it has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is those 2 cells containing whitespaces (blank, tabs or emtpy string). To handle them in general, just use `str.strip` before compare to `''`. You may assign directly using `loc` and boolean mask on equal of `''`

```
df_74034.loc[df_74034['data/hora'].str.strip().eq(''), 'data/hora'] = t.HumTechRoom


Out[1891]:
                    data/hora  HumExamRoom                 HumTechRoom  \
0  2017-08-18\t09:22:33\t65.9          NaN  2017-08-18\t09:22:33\t65.9
1  2017-10-03\t11:08:26\t60.5          NaN  2017-10-03\t11:08:26\t60.5
2        2018-02-17\t01:45:24          NaN                        69.7
3        2018-02-17\t01:45:55          NaN                        67.5
4        2018-02-17\t01:46:29          NaN                        65.4
5        2018-02-17\t01:47:20          NaN                        63.3
6        2018-02-17\t01:48:35          NaN                        61.3
7        2018-02-17\t01:49:08          NaN                        63.4
8        2018-02-17\t01:49:31          NaN                        65.5

   Machine  TempExamRoom  TempTechRoom
0    74034           NaN           NaN
1    74034           NaN           NaN
2    74034           NaN           NaN
3    74034           NaN           NaN
4    74034           NaN           NaN
5    74034           NaN           NaN
6    74034           NaN           NaN
7    74034           NaN           NaN
8    74034           NaN           NaN
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your post. What is "t" in `t.HumTechRoom`? Anyway, I've replaced it by `df_74034.HumTechRoom` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
missing_hour = df['data/hora'].isna()

df.loc[missing_hour, 'data/hora'] = df.loc[missing_hour,'HumTechRoom']
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I appreciate that. Look, I'm not interested in all the information in the column 'HumTechRoom', but only that part which corresponds to date/time. And I am just interested in changing the values of the cells 0 and 1 of the column 'data/hora'.

Comment: `df[missing_hour]['data/hora]` would throw a warning. Use `df.loc[missing, 'data/hora']` instead.

Comment: Marlon, The problem you want to solve is the unformated string `2017-08-18\t09:22:33\t65.9`? Could you please specify what is the desired output?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I appreciate that, @VictorHugoBorges. No, the problem I want to solve is to change the value of the first two rows in the column 'data/hora'.

Comment: By the way, unfortunately, it didn't work, @QuangHoang. For me, it is a mister why.

Comment: Oh, I see what is going on! You dont have missings, you just have blank inputs. Could you please tell me what is the value of `df_74034.iloc[0,0]`? Is this a empty string, string with a space?

Comment: @VictorHugoBorges you've got it! I don't know yet! I'm not on the PC now, but tomorrow I'll try to tell you. 
Another strategy may be to drop that first values and then add two new ones later. Anyway, for now, I would like to thank you so much for your time! :)